# Assigning pointer to a CLR type to void* using unsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Is there any way to assign a pointer to a CLR type to a `void*` in a C# `unsafe` block?

```
var bar = 1;
var foo = new Foo();

unsafe
{
    void* p1 = &bar;
    void* p2 = &foo; // fails at compile time
}
```

Or this only possible using C++/CLI:

```
System::Text::StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew System::Text::StringBuilder();
void* p1 = &sb;
```

Can't find any way to make it work in C#

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why do you need a void pointer to it?

Comment: doesn't have to be a void pointer, but I need a pointer to a value that can be either a primitive like int or a complex type like System.Text.StringBuilder without having to differ between them, and that doesn't box the int (aka. can't treat it like "Object", to slow)

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you should consider using generics. Generics are the C# way of dealing with a variety of types without boxing the value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx):

> Any of the following types may be a
>   pointer type:
>
> - sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int,    uint, long, ulong, char, float,
>     double, decimal, or bool.
> - Any enum type.
> - Any pointer type.
> - Any user-defined struct type that contains fields of unmanaged types
>     only.

There's no way to have a pointer to an instance of a class (e.g. pointer to an instance of `System.Text.StringBuilder`), although you can have a pointer to a class member in the `fixed` context, as in the following code:

```
class Test
{
static int x;
int y;
unsafe static void F(int* p) {
    *p = 1;
}
static void Main() {
    Test t = new Test();
    int[] a = new int[10];
    unsafe {
        fixed (int* p = &x) F(p);
        fixed (int* p = &t.y) F(p); // pointer to a member of a class 
        fixed (int* p = &a[0]) F(p);
        fixed (int* p = a) F(p);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a pointer to a managed object, it must be `fixed` so that the GC knows not to move the object around.

Comment: How would that look for a managed object? I can only find examples dealing with int or byte.

Comment: All I'm getting is this error "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type" at compile time